# How to add corporate calendar to apple calendar in iphone

Tags: iphone, gmail, ical, google-calendar

I work at a company where we need to install admin profile in iphone to get access to corporate mail and calendar. Only option to access those without company profile in my phone is to use Gmail and Google calendar. I am ok to use Gmail as email client but I want to use apple calendar instead of google calendar. Is there a way I can sync my google calendar to apple calendar ?

Comment: Google has articles on this. Set up a Google (Gmail) account and only turn on Calendar (in the account setup), is what they boil down to.

Comment: We might need quite a bit more details to guess why a profile is needed - what it allows and whether you can side-step that. I agree with Steve's gentle reminder to show some research and explain why what you found didn't work - with an error message or a step that failed. Let's regroup once you can edit some details in the body - help us help you by showing some research and clarifying what error you see. If you're just looking for a guide - show us what you searched for and why that guide isn't good enough with specifics.

Comment: @SteveChambers I read those google articles and have my personal google account's calendar added to apple calendar (by turning on calendar in settings->passwords&accounts->account->calendar). When I tried to do the same with corp mail account, it just does not login at all

Comment: @bmike the profile my company has is admin profile, so it can control my device remotely. It does not access photos, videos and other application's data but I do not want to have it on my phone as there is a chance for them to control my personal phone.

Comment: Then the profile likely controls what app you can use to access calendar and mail. The profile you **AGREED TO INSTALL** now controls your phone. Not much you can do unless this is so onerous that you must resign.